# SequenceFile format with Hadoop Streaming Python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

Does Hadoop officially support [streaming with binary formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700580/266457) as of 0.21?

The [hadoop-streaming.jar](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming) accepts an `inputFormat` that is a Java class name. How do you provide the Hadoop streaming job this Java class?  Besides executing [hadoop-streaming.jar](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopStreaming) with inputFormat, outputFormat arguments, what else must be done to run a Python streaming job with SequenceFile input/output format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It loos like some muddy documentation.

Try reading these answers

[How to use Hadoop Streaming with LZO-compressed Sequence Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060967/how-to-use-hadoop-streaming-with-lzo-compressed-sequence-files/6364689#6364689)

[Python read file as stream from HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485718/python-read-file-as-stream-from-hdfs)

and don't worry about Sequencefile. It's not worth it.